# Examples of algebraic structures that live at the intersection of varieties and antivarieties?

Tags: logic, reference-request, universal-algebra

In Universal Algebra, by an *equational* *variety* of algebras we mean the class of all algebraic structures of a given signature satisfying certain (conjunctions of) identities. Dually, an *antivariety* satisfies certain disjunctions of negated equations (a.k.a. anti-identities). 
Moreover, by a *disjunction of polynomial equations* (DE) we mean a disjunction of identities. Obviously, an identity is a particular (degenerate) case of DE. Furthermore, one might note that anti-identities and DEs are, respectively, particular cases of Horn clauses and [dual Horn clauses](https://mathoverflow.net/q/202819/34544).

Some well-known classes of algebraic structures are very naturally characterized by a set of axioms containing both anti-identities and DEs. For instance, [field axioms](http://people.reed.edu/~mayer/math112.html/html1/node16.html) include an anti-identity (the 'zero-one law'), and a number of DEs, including a non-degenerate one that consists in a disjunction that deals with the multiplicative inverses of non-zero elements ('for any given field element, either it is zero or it has a multiplicative inverse'). If one *generalizes* the above definitions for signatures having relational symbols in the natural way (having positive literals replace identities, and negative literals replace anti-identities), other more or less natural examples of structures whose axiomatizations mix generalized anti-identities and generalized DEs may be found in Graph Theory (an example: [connected](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConnectedGraph.html) [oriented](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrientedGraph.html) graphs).

Are there other well-known 'natural' and 'useful' examples of algebraic structures axiomatized by both DEs and anti-identities, in Mathematics or Computer Science?

Comment: The first-order theory of graphs is not an algebraic structure, so it's not a good example. Also a disjunction of equations is not a particular case of a Horn clause.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @RobArthan. I will omit the example from Graph Theory, as it indeed requires the signature to be augmented with relation symbols. As for DEs not being a particular case of a Horn clause, I had meant to write *dual Horn clauses* (i.e., "disjunctions of literals with at most one negated literal"), exactly as in the link that I had added from the beginning. Shall fix that. Thanks again.

Comment: Fixed, @RobArthan. Note that I ended up not omitting the example from Graph Theory, but rather modifying it minimally to have it making sense (I do hope it is clear now!).